# Solve for x in logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem. I don't know if it's possible but thought it would be worth asking.

Simply solve for $x$.

$$s=\left(\frac{x^2}{n}+x\right)\ln\left(\frac{n+x}{x}\right)$$

WolframAlpha doesn't solve it. I can't seem to solve it.  So I figured it might take some more advanced technique.

Comment: Are $s$, $x$ and $n$ variables or constants?

Comment: Yes you may think of them as constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mix of logs and polynomials is a problem.  If $x \gg n$ you can write 
$$s=\left(\frac{x^2}{n}+x\right)\ln\left(\frac{n+x}{x}\right)\\=\left(\frac{x^2}{n}+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{n}{x}\right)\\
\approx \left(\frac{x^2}{n}+x\right)\frac nx\\
=x+n\\
x=s-n$$
This will work when $n$ is small compared to $s$.  The error will be of order $(\frac nx)^2.$  Otherwise you are in for a numeric solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Millikan already answered, you will need some numerical method (such as Newton method for example) to solve this transcendental equation and this means that you will need a "good" starting point.

Assuming that $x$ could be large, we can built the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant for infinitely large values of $x$ and get by the end (after simplifications)
$$s \approx x+\frac{n (n+6 x)}{6 (n+2 x)}$$ which reduces to a quadratic equation in $x$
$$x^2+ (n-s)x+\frac{n (n-6 s)}{12} =0$$ which shows two roots since $\Delta=\frac{2 }{3}n^2+s^2 >0$. The one to keep is given by
$$x_0=\frac{s-n} 2+\frac{ \sqrt{6 n^2+9 s^2}}{6}$$

For illustration purposes, let us try using $n=123.456$ and $s=789.012$. This could give
$x_0\approx 730.49$. Now, using Newton method, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 730.490477415532 \\
 1 & 730.494365219568 \\
 2 & 730.494365219646
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

Keeping the same value for $n$ but using now $s=78.9012$, xe would have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 41.7271349671412 \\
 1 & 43.3226603413356 \\
 2 & 43.3300991145702 \\
 3 & 43.3300992693775
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Assuming $x$ to be large, we could perform the Taylor series expansion of the rhs and get
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{n}+x\right)\log\left(\frac{n+x}{x}\right)=x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n^2}{6 x}+\frac{n^3}{12 x^2}-\frac{n^4}{20 x^3}+\frac{n^5}{30
   x^4}-\frac{n^6}{42 x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ Then, using series reversion
$$x=s-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n^2}{6 s}-\frac{7 n^4}{360 s^3}+\frac{139 n^6}{30240
   s^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{s^6}\right)$$ For the worked examples, this would give $730.494$ and $45.4946$.